# Why does Prolog repeat the last value of my list after semicolon?

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

I'm attempting to create my own sorting rule in Prolog, and after a lot of trial and error, I was able to get it to work except that when I press the ; in swipl, it will add on the last value of my list to the list.

The code used is as follows:

min finds a minimum value in a list and returns it

```
min([H|[]],H).
min([H|T],Min) :- 
    min(T,CurrentMin),
    H < CurrentMin,
    Min = H.
min([H|T],Min) :- 
    min(T,CurrentMin),
    CurrentMin =< H,
    Min = CurrentMin.
```

remove finds the element you wish to remove in a list, and returns a list with the element removed

```
remove(_,[],[]).
remove(First,[First|Rest],Rest).
remove(Element,[First|Rest],[First|RestLessElement]) :-
    remove(Element,Rest,RestLessElement).
```

Finally, sort_inc attempts to use the above rules to create a sorted list in increasing order.

```
sort_inc([H|[]],[H]).
sort_inc(UnOrderedList,[H|OrderedTail]) :-
    min(UnOrderedList,H),
    remove(H,UnOrderedList,T),
    sort_inc(T,OrderedTail).
```

The sorting works great, but when I press the semicolon in swipl after running the rule on a list, it will repeat the last value in the list as so:

```
sort_inc([3,6,8,4],List).
List = [3, 4, 6, 8] ;
List = [3, 4, 6, 8, 8] ;
List = [3, 4, 6, 8, 8, 8] ;
List = [3, 4, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8] ;
List = [3, 4, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8] ;
List = [3, 4, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8] ;
List = [3, 4, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8|...] .
```

Why does it repeat this last value instead of returning false when the semicolon is entered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have problem in your remove/3 implementation, try this instead:

```
remove(X, [X|Rest], Result) :-
    !, remove_sub(X, [X|Rest], Result).
remove(X, [Y|Rest], Z) :-
    X \= Y,
    remove(X, Rest, RestRemoved),
    Z = [Y|RestRemoved].
remove(_, [], []).

remove_sub(X, [X|Rest], Rest).
remove_sub(X, [Y|Rest], Z) :-
    remove_sub(X, Rest, RestRemoved),
    Z = [Y|RestRemoved].
```

To be exact, your first clause of remove/3 generates improper solution by leaving list intact even if the element to be removed is its member:

```
?- remove(1, [1, 2, 3], L).
L = [2, 3] ;
L = [1, 2, 3].
```

Also, please keep in mind, that many Prolog implementations will have remove/3 and min/2 implementations (as well as sort, of course) bundled. For example, Swi-Prolog includes:

- delete/3, which does almost what your what your remove/3 was supposed to do, except it removes all instances of element at once
- select/3, which does almost what your remove/3 was supposed to do, except it does not allow removal of elements which are not present in list
- min_list/2 and min_member/2, to find min elements of list
- sort/2, msort/2, predsort/3, to do the actual sorting

Even if your aim is to create your custom implementation, it is still worth to use them to test your own implementation, e.g. you could quickly replace call to your remove/3 with delete/3 to find out where the problem is.

Comment: By the first clause of remove/3, are you referring to remove(_,[],[])? I thought this would only return an empty list if anything is attempted to be removed from an empty list. I thought this would be a good last recursive step if the element doesn't belong.

Comment: Also, in the remove rule you've written, remove(1,[2],List) returns List = []. I don't want a single element list to lose its item without the proper call.

Comment: Seems you are right, my initial implementation of remove/3 was broken, sorry. This is now fixed (hopefully), I've updated the answer. Also, delete/3 I've mentioned also differs from our remove/3 in that it deletes all occurrences of element "instantly", while remove/3 removes them one-by-one during the backtracking.

Comment: As per your question - yes, I was referring to remove(_,[],[]). It is required, indeed, but it also generates improper solution if used as per your implementation. The new implementation (see updated answer) allows usage of it only if we hadn't found any occurrence of element to be removed so far.
In other words, if there is no element x in list we want to remove, we allow usage of remove( _ ,[],[]). Otherwise (we've found x already, but just want to continue backtracking to see if we can find more solutions), we are not allowing its usage.